# Ajax drop down database

Tags: mysql, ajax

I want to create a dropdown list where it is list the data from database and when I press on of them, it give detail of the item. How should I do it? Here is some explanation on how I want to do it. In a dropdown list I have users from the database and when I click one of the user, it tell's me the detail of the user using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you and your case.

- One option is getting the data with all the details (it will slow the initial loading depending on how big your records are).
- You can, on the other hand, get simplified data and get the data by id for details on every click.

Which one is right? Totally depends.